# PhpUnit testing repositories Symfony findOneBy

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I am net to phpunit in Symfony 3 and I'm wondering what exactly should I follow when testing a repository. For example, I have the following repo function:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function findAdminRole()
{
    $role = $this->repository->findOneBy(['name' => Role::ADMIN]);

    if (null === $role) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    return $role;
}
```

What exactly a test for this would look like? Should I test that the function findOneBy and the NotFoundException are called or to get real data values? I am kinda stuck here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ok so findOneBY returns either Null or an Object, you can set up sample data which would return either Null or say a role object and test for that, here's something in my opinion to help you get started.
so, in the setup i would mock the repository:

```
   $this->mockRepository = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('path to the respository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('if you want to stub any'))
            ->getMock();
$this->object = new class( //this is the class under test
// all your other mocked services, ex : logger or anything else
)
```

now we have a mock of the repo, lets see how the sample tests would look like

1st test

```
   public function findAdminRoleTestReturnsException(){
    $name = ['name' => Role::ABC]; // consider this will return Null result from DB due to whatever reason
    $exception = new NotFoundException();
    // do whatever other assertions you need here
      $this->mockRepository->expects($this->any())
                ->method('findOneBY')
                ->with($name)
                ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    // Now call the function
    $role = $this->object->findAdminRole();
$this->assertEquals($exception, $role);
    }
```

in the same manner above you can write another test like:
2nd test

```
public function findAdminRoleTestReturnsNewRole(){
$name = ['name' => Role::ADMIN] // this will find the entry in theDB
$ testRoleObject = new Role();
$this->mockRepository->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('findOneBY')
                    ->with($name)
                    ->will($this->returnValue($testRoleObject));
        // Now call the function
        $role = $this->object->findAdminRole();
    $this->assertEquals($testRoleObject, $role);
}
```

hope this helps